# Angular2 Selector did not match any elements in nested Components

Tags: angular

I have two nested `@Components` en angular 2. The view renders just fine but it always throws a javascript error the first time.
Here is my code in Typescript.

App HTML:

```
<body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

App Component:

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {CanvasComponent} from "./CanvasComponent";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>My Games</h2>
      <div>
        <my-canvas></my-canvas>
      </div>
  `,
  directives: [CanvasComponent]
})

class AppComponent {
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Canvas Component:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-canvas'
})

@View({
  template: `
  <div>
    <span>Balls:</span>
    <div>{{canvas.length}}</div>
  </div>
  `
})

export class CanvasComponent {
  canvas = [1,2,3];
}

bootstrap(CanvasComponent);
```

The error is:

```
EXCEPTION: The selector "my-canvas" did not match any elements
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Remove `bootstrap(CanvasComponent)` from your `CanvasComponent` file. It's trying to bootstrap application second time using `CanvasComponent` as a root and looking for `my-canvas` element in your App HTML. Of course it can't find it.

Comment: Okay, now let's say `CanvasComponent` requires `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and other services. How would you inject it? I feel like the root component should care about injecting these services.

Comment: @Pablo, just add it to the bootstrap call for your App `bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);` Then add a constructor to CanvasComponent with the parameter you need annotated with `@Inject`, e.g.: `constructor(@Inject(Http) public http: Http) {}`

Comment: @svallory thanks, I've accomplished DI by using the `providers` property inside the @Component. See https://github.com/ghpabs/angular2-seed-project/blob/master/src/scripts/todo/todo.component.ts#L12-L17. This way I find the component is better encapsulated. Thoughts?

Comment: @Pablo that's a good way to go if you want to provide, let's say TodoService, only for that component. For services like `ApiService` and `Http`, which are used across the app and should always be configured the same way, you should provide them from the app bootstrap.

Answer (score 23):

I fixed the issue by changing the name in the index.html, you should be sure that the tag in the index.html are the same selector that in the main component.

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
         <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
      </head>
      <!-- 3. Display the application -->

      <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app> <!-- THIS TAG SHOULD BE THE SAME THAT THE SELECTOR IN THE MAIN COMPONENT -->
      </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my index.html, I was missing

```
<base href="/">
```

So the minimum that needs to be there is

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <your-selector></your-selector>
</body>
</html>
```